# receiving a server response and sending it to the browser?

Tags: c, http, network-programming

This is a portion of a basic proxy server I'm writing. This code reads a server response to an HTTP request, then writes it back to the client (browser). When I test it with firefox, it loads most of my homepage, but cannot load images. It then freezes and I can't load anything else after that initial page. Probably because I'm failing to close the connection properly so that it can make another request to my proxy. I'm not sure how to do that.

The terminal output here stops at "Finished." It doesn't print "Started over," but nor does it print "Exited while loop." So I can't figure out where it's getting stuck, or how to properly conclude the connection so that after loading Google I can actually initiate a Google search, or load Gmail, or anything.

```
while( (n = read(sock, buffer2, 1024 ) ) >= 1)
  {
      printf("Started over: %i :(\n\n", n);

      buffer2[n] = '\0';
      printf( "Rcvd message from server: \n\n----\n\n%s\n\n----\n\n", buffer2 );
      n = write( newsock, buffer2, strlen( buffer2 ) );

      printf("\n\nFinished.\n\n");
  }

  close( sock );
  printf("\n\nExited while loop.\n\n");
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of this another question you posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728653/handling-a-server-response-and-sending-it-the-browser ; perhaps you should delete this one.

Comment: yeah i know but i was desperate for an answer and i was not getting one-- i know it's a bad thing. i wouldnt normally do it. i will delete the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Check the return code from `read` for both zero and negative values.
  `n > 0`   means `n` bytes of data are available
  `n == 0` means the peer has closed the connection
  `n < 0`   indicates an error.
- If your socket is non-blocking, don't exit the loop on an `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` error, which mean that no data is available, but the connection is still open (so more data may be coming).
- Check the return code from `write` also.
- The data returned from a socket can be binary (which is why `read` returns the number of bytes it received).  If the data happens to contain a zero byte, the `printf` will truncate its output at that point, and `strlen` will cause the `write` to behave similarly.  Be sure to print/write all `n` bytes.
- Run the code in a debugger, so you can *really* see what's going on.